# how to center images vertically woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to center the image vertically, on woo-commerce, i tried vertical align , min height, but nothing is working, maybe i am picking something wrong and i cant notice it? For example i want "ARZ" image to be in the middle not to the top.
Here is the link:

https://carloshaidamous.com/product-category/prints

```css
.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail.size-woocommerce_thumbnail.wp-post-image {
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `height` to `.products li`, then add the following styles to each `anchor` tag within `li` element.

```
.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

You can also check out https://masonry.desandro.com/ , if that's what you want.

Comment: worked perfectly but now the title is on the right side instead of bottom

Comment: give the `anchor` tag `flex-direction: column`. You also may need to adjust the top margin of the `ul`.